# Wordpress - How to fix the if / else code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to show a different style depending on the current category. So I'm trying to use the if/else to do it. But, when i load the page, nothing appears...

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
$current_section = single_cat_title(); 

     if ($current_section == "music") {
?>

        <li class="music_post"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </a></li>

<?php 
     } 
     elseif ($current_section == "blog") 
     {
?>

        <li class="blog_post"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </a></li>


 <?php 
      } 
 ?>
 <? endwhile;?>
 <? endif; ?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, and what happens instead? What have you tried and why doesn't it work?

Comment: $current_section is music or blog? add another else to default value

Comment: i'm trying to show different style for the blog category and for the music category. So, i add the if/else, but nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the terms so:

```
 global $post;
 $terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'name_of_taxonomy');
```

This returns an array of useful values, in which you can use:

```
$currentTerm = $terms[0]->slug;
```

Now you can check

```
if ($currentTerm == 'music'){
 // ...
}else{
//...
}
```

Sorry, use this instead:

```
$terms = $wp_query->queried_object;;
echo $terms->slug;
```

Comment: Hello! It show's a fatal error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home/landserver/jorgeferreiro/wp-content/themes/jorge_ferreiro/category.php on line 60

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<?php 

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'name_of_taxonomy');
$current_section = $terms[0]->slug;
if ($current_section != "") {
?>

<li class="<?php if ($current_section == "music") { ?>music_post<?php } elseif ($current_section == "blog") {?>blog_post<?php } ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
   <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</a></li>

<?php } ?>

 <? endwhile;?>
 <? endif; ?>
```